# Symfonyで文字列のキャメルケースとスネークケースを変換するには

Tags: php, symfony2

Symfonyを使っています。

プロパティの名前などに使っている文字列を、キャメルケースとスネークケースで相互に変換したいのですが、フレームワークのクラスなどで簡単にできるでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfonyであれば、`DependencyInjection`コンポーネントの`Container`クラスに、`camelize()`メソッドと`underscore()`メソッドがあります(staticメソッド)。Symfonyのみで動作することが前提であれば、これを使うのが手っ取り早いです。

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
...

$foo = Container::camelize($bar);
```

自分のプロジェクトではなく、Symfony自体への機能追加・修正などの場合も同様です。

また、自分のプロジェクト固有の部分であれば、[Stringy](https://github.com/danielstjules/Stringy)のように文字列処理一般に使えるライブラリがあるため、こちらへ寄せてしまう手もあります。上記コードをStringyを使った場合は、次のようになります。

```
use Stringy\StaticStringy as String;
...

$foo = String::camelize($bar);
```